# Update bundled JRE - Install4j

Tags: install4j

My application's JRE is JRE1.6_24.

Added the JRE1.7_25 bundle into the Add-on installer using install4j.

Update bundled JRE is selected in my Add-on installer.

On executing Add-On installer, it is not updating the JRE of already installed application.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the "Add-on" installer type, it will never update the bundled JRE. Only regular installers will do that.